# Assigning a function to a property of an object affecting other instances?

Tags: javascript, this

So I'm adding a function as a property to my *class* via the construct arguments, like so.

```
var Class = function (options) {
  this.a  = options.a;
  this.b  = options.b;
  this.fn = options.fn;
};

Class.prototype.fn = function () { return 1; };

var instance = new Class({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  fn: function () { return 2; }
});
```

For whatever reason I believe for whatever reason one of the functions are shared among other instances. I'll include the actual code I'm writing. For brevity here's my actual constructor...

```
var QueryProperty = function (options) {
  if (options.writePath) {
    this.writePath = options.writePath;
  }
  else {
    throw new TypeError("Argument writePath need to specified");
  }

  this.readPath = options.readPath || null;

  if (options.transformation) {
    this._transformation = options.transformation;
  }

  if (options.isSpecified) {
    this._isSpecified = options.isSpecified;
  }
};
```

I've tried the following,

- binding the function within the constructor, with `Function.prototype.bind`.
- Tried using some static method on QueryProperty that would create an instance then assign the functions to the object outside the constructor.
- Some random npm library based on JQuerys extend method, along with `_.extend`, & the built in `Object.create`.
- And a few other related things, none of which worked.

Here's where I'm creating instance of the objects

```
var toNum = function (n) { return parseInt(n, 10); };

var properties = [
  new QueryProperty({
     readPath: 'activities',
     writePath: [0, '$match', 'incident', '$match', 'activity'],
     transformation: toNum,
   }),
   new QueryProperty({
     readPath: 'cause',
     writePath: [0, '$match', 'incident', '$match', 'cause'],
     transformation: toNum,
   }),
   new QueryProperty({
     readPath: 'fatal',
     writePath: [0, '$match', 'incident', '$match', 'fatal'],
     transformation: function (param) {
       return param !== 'false';
     },
     isSpecified: function (params) {
       return params[this.readPath].indexOf(',') === -1;
     }
   })
 ];
```

The weird thing is, everything behaves just fine until I've included the `isSpecified` in the last `QueryProperty` instance. Part of me thinks it might be the use of `this` in the function might have screwed everything up, as when you call `this.isSpecified` and you log the property `this.readPath` it says `'fatal'`, this was even after I bound the properties to the object in the constructor. It's also interesting as it happens when I also prefix the variable with an underscore, like so `_readPath`.

This code is all for a Node.js server incase that's relevant.

### edit:

The `_isSpecified` method is being called here.

```
QueryProperty.prototype.apply = function (urlQuery, dbQuery) {
  if (this._isSpecified(urlQuery)) {
    this._pathInit.forEach(function (prop) {
      if (!dbQuery[prop]) {
        dbQuery[prop] = {};
      }
      dbQuery = dbQuery[prop];
    });
    dbQuery[this._pathLast] = this._getWriteValue(urlQuery);
  }
};
```

`this._pathInit` & `this._pathLast` are both properties, defined by `Object.defineProperties`, but I only say this so you know where these properties are coming from.

### all the code

The Property module

```
var _ = require('underscore');

/** 
 * class QueryProperty
 *   Properties
 *     - _readPath  :: Maybe[String]
 *     - _writePath :: Union(Array[String], String)
 *     - _pathInit  :: Array[String]
 *     - _pathLast  :: String
 *   Functions
 *     - apply           :: Object -> Object -> undefined 
 *     - isSpecified     :: Object -> Boolean
 *     - _transformation :: Any -> Any
 *     - _getWriteValue  :: -> Any
 */

var Class = function (options) {
  if (options.writePath) {
    this._writePath = options.writePath;
  }
  else {
    throw new TypeError("Arguement writePath need to specified");
  }

  this._readPath = options.readPath || null;

  if (options.transformation) {
    this._transformation = options.transformation.bind(this);
  }

  if (options.isSpecified) {
    this._isSpecified = options.isSpecified.bind(this);
  }
};

// determines if a urlQuery property is specified
Class.prototype._isSpecified = function (inQuery) {
  if (this._readPath !== null) {
    var ref = inQuery[this._readPath]; 
    return !(ref === undefined || ref === null);
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
};

// takes read value & does some preprocessing
Class.prototype._transformation = function (x) { return x; }; 

Class.prototype._getWriteValue = function (inQuery){
  if (this._readPath !== null) {
    return this._transformation(inQuery[this._readPath]);
  }
  else {
    return this._transformation(inQuery);
  }
}; 

Object.defineProperties(Class.prototype, {
  // gets everything in the path except the last element
  readPath: {
    get: function () {
      return this._readPath;
    }
  },
  _pathInit: {
    get: function () {
      return _.isArray(this._writePath) ? 
        _.initial(this._writePath) : [];
    },
  },
  // gets the last element in the path
  _pathLast: {
    get: function () {
      return _.isArray(this._writePath) ? 
        _.last(this._writePath) : this._writePath;
    }
  }
});

Class.prototype.apply = function (urlQuery, dbQuery) {
  console.log(this._readPath);
  if (this._isSpecified(urlQuery)) {
    this._pathInit.forEach(function (prop) {
      if (!dbQuery[prop]) { 
        dbQuery[prop] = {}; 
      } 
      dbQuery = dbQuery[prop];
    }); 
    dbQuery[this._pathLast] = this._getWriteValue(urlQuery); 
  }
};

Class.create = function (obj) {
  var _new = new Class({
    writePath: obj.writePath,
    readPath: obj.readPath,    
  });

  _new._transformation = obj.transformation;
  _new._isSpecified = obj.isSpecified;

  return _new;
};

module.exports = Class;
```

The module calling it.

```
var _             = require('underscore'),
    QueryProperty = require('./property'),

    Module,
    properties,
    generateQuery;

/**
 * Used to make the difference between the 
 * parameters used in the http requests url 
 * query, & the location within the mongo
 * document structure. 
 */
var urlEncodeToMongoLookUp = {
  location: '',
  activities: 'incident.activity',
  cause: 'incident.cause',
  occupation: 'occupation.occupation',
  industry: '',
  injuries: 'incident.injury',
  workload: '',
  fatal: 'incident.fatal', 
  age: ''
};

var toNum = function (n) {
  return parseInt(n, 10);
};

/**
 * Properties of the query
 */
properties = [
  new QueryProperty({
    readPath: 'location',
    writePath: [0, '$match', 'incident', '$match', 'bodyLocation'],
    transformation: toNum,
  }),
  new QueryProperty({
    readPath: 'activities',
    writePath: [0, '$match', 'incident', '$match', 'activity'],
    transformation: toNum,
  }),
  new QueryProperty({
    readPath: 'cause',
    writePath: [0, '$match', 'incident', '$match', 'cause'],
    transformation: toNum,
  }),
  new QueryProperty({
    readPath: 'fatal',
    writePath: [0, '$match', 'incident', '$match', 'fatal'],
    transformation: function (param) {
      return param !== 'false'; 
    },
    isSpecified: function (param) {
      return param[this.readPath].indexOf(',') === -1;
    }
  }),
  new QueryProperty({
    readPath: 'occupation',
    writePath: [0, '$match', 'occupation', '$match', 'occupation'],
    transformation: toNum,
  }),
  new QueryProperty({
    readPath: 'grouping',
    writePath: [1, '$group', 'description'],
    transformation: function (grouping) {
      return '$' + urlEncodeToMongoLookUp[grouping];
    },
  }),
  new QueryProperty({
    readPath: 'grouping',
    writePath: [1, '$group', 'value'],
    transformation: function () { return { $sum: 1 }; },
  }),
];


generateQuery = function (rawQuery) {
  var mongoQuery = [];

  properties.forEach(function (prop) {
    prop.apply(rawQuery, mongoQuery);
  });

  return mongoQuery;
};


module.exports = Module = function (collection) {
  return function (rawQuery, callback) {
    collection.aggregate(generateQuery(rawQuery), callback);  
  };
};

Module.generateQuery = generateQuery;
```

Comment: Please show us where `.fn`/`._isSpecified`/`.isSpecified` is called.

Comment: @Bergi Mentioned in the edit.

Comment: And how does this `apply` method work with the `properties` array you declared with those 3 QueryProperties? Also, what is wrong with `this.readPath` being `'fatal'` in the `isSpecified` call, that's just the value you gave to the last instance? What else did you expect?

Comment: Can you give a clear, executable example that reproduces the problem and explain exactly what you expect and how the actual output differs?  The only thing you've said is that "for whatever reason, I believe that this method is being shared."  By reducing the problem to a small, reproducible example, you might even find the issue.

Comment: To begin with http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/9QX5C/ :)

Comment: @Bergi it was the same for all instances, I'll provide the full code sample.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Now what's wrong with it? What results does it give that you did not expect?

Comment: Like the title says `Assigning a function to a property of an object affecting other instances?`. The `PropertyQuery` class has a method called `isSpecified` which is used to validate input, the default behaviour checks if a a property is defined. I've passed for whatever reason, on of the instances who overrides the default behaviour in the instance also overrides the default behaviour in other instances. This does not happen with the transformation function. Where each instance has it's own version of the function.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Hmm that should not be happening. Something is mutating state. Edit, oh wait scrap that, that is what I wanted to happen.

Comment: I'm going to bed, I'll respond to any updates in the morning (it's 2:35am here). Apologises if anyone is looking a response.

Comment: I tried to work on this (made most of it executable in a jsFiddle so I could debug it), but I got stuck because I don't have appropriate data that I can call it with.  If you can supply the data you would pass to `generateQuery()`, I might be able to make some progress.

Comment: I do see a potential problem issue with `Class.create()` depending upon exactly how it is used, but you don't appear to be using that so that must be some other issue.  It is also very bizarre (and I think a bad practice) to override `.apply()` because that has a regular definition with Function.prototype.apply that can be very useful.  I'd suggest changing the name of your `.apply()` method to something that doesn't conflict with built-in methods.  You also should not have to use `.bind()` when you are as long as you're calling things appropriately.